# NSDate Conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I'm attempting to convert a date from MMM dd, YYYY to YYYY-MM-dd.

```
    NSDateFormatter *importDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [importDateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY"];

    NSDate *importedDate = [importDateFormat dateFromString:expiresOn.text];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

    NSString *dateImported = [dateFormat stringFromDate:importedDate];
```

The date brought in from the expiresOn.text (label) is:
Oct 08, 2012

The date contained in dateImported after conversion is:
2011-12-25

Am I missing something? Is there something wrong with my date formatter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are two things wrong, first is `yyyy` not `YYYYY` and since you are parsing the month as a word you need to tell the date formatter which language to expect.

```
NSDateFormatter *importDateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[importDateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
importDateFormat.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"] autorelease];

NSDate *importedDate = [importDateFormat dateFromString:expiresOn.text];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *dateImported = [dateFormat stringFromDate:importedDate];
```

If you are using ARC, then remove the autorelease part in the `NSLocale`; if you are not using ARC, you need to release the `NSDateFormatter`.